# sort utility on cyrillic text

Tags: mac, unix

I have to sort some lines of cyrillic characters and I want to use the sort utility (on MAC OS X 10.6).
The problem is that result is incorrect.
I take the text into clipboard, then run
pbpaste | sort
This is plaintext data, and I also tried passing a file to the sort command.

My source data is

```
Биатлон
Арбуз
Фото
Пума
Перина
Новость
Карандаш
Перина с двумя пододеяльниками
Карикатура
Куст
Фигура
```

And after sorting I get

```
Куст
Пума
Фото
Арбуз
Перина
Фигура
Перина с двумя пододеяльниками
Биатлон
Новость
Карандаш
Карикатура
```

Theese lines aren’t even grouped by first letter.
I tried option -d, but then I get an error

sort: string comparison failed: Illegal byte sequence
sort: Set LC_ALL='C' to work around the problem.
sort: The strings compared were `\320\321\321\321' and`\320\320\320\321\321\320’.

Exporting the variable as recommended doesn’t solve the problem.
What can I do to use the sort utility for such a task?
Any additional info is necessary?

Answer (score 3):

I believe you need to set the locale.  I think you can do this:

```
LC_ALL="ru" pbpaste | sort
```

(The first part sets the LC_ALL environment variable for the duration of the command.)

I'm running Leopard.  When I issue a pbpaste, all characters are substituted for question marks.  I did save the text to a UTF-8-encoded file called sort_temp.txt, and running:

```
sort sort_temp.txt
```

gives the same improperly sorted list that you posted, but running

```
LC_ALL="ru" sort sort_temp.txt
```

or

```
LANG="ru" sort sort_temp.txt
```

gives a properly sorted list.

Answer (score 0):

Try to save the data in unicode encoded (or UTF8) file, and if sort utility is unicode enabled, it should work. I guess, the problem is that pbpaste does not set the encoding properly. I'm not Mac user, so its just a guess.

Comment: I've also tried with UTF-8 file, but since the result was the same I didn’t mention it.